# How add the string in listview and strech it in row?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, stretch

Create one listview and add the item in listview like

```
listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("hello i am working in C#");
```

I would like to output like this:

```
hello i am working in C#
```

Instead of this i am getting like this:

```
hello.....
```

When click that I got like this:

```
hello i
am working in
C#
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: FYI, `WinForms` and `WPF` are extremely useful tags

Comment: Indeed that was going to be my first question too. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `listView1.View=View.List;`

For more information: [ListView.View Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view.aspx)